# Joining 3 tables was 1 table performance MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

in a school management system, we need to incorporate 3 semester grades for each subject by each student.

after a discussion, i came up with two solutions.

**solution 1**

create 3 tables for each semester. (gradeSemester1, gradeSemester2, gradeSemester3)

**solution 2**

create 1 table called, semesterGrades and with a type handle all 3 semesters.

the reason for solution 1 is to stop data duplication. for example, if there is 8 subjects for a student. this can only contain 8 records in a table where as in solution 2 it can contain up to 24 records of a single student.

what will be the best solution when performance is a major concern ? why solution 2 is better ?

Comment: This is a case of premature optimization.  Use properly normalized data!  It is what MYSQL is designed to perform the fastest with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to change the Database structure depending on the data, so creating a new table whenever you need a new semester is bad design. 
All you need is one extra table to store the grades. However I would personally not store them in columns, but in rows to be more flexible (maybe some day you want more than the grades of only 3 semesters).

The table would look like this:

```
ID | StudentID | SemesterID | SubjectID | Grade
```

Another advantage of this approach is that you know which semester a grade belongs to. If you have 3 columns for the grades, you only know the grades but you have no information about the semester (I'm guessing he could take more than 3 semesters if needed).

Also I would not worry about performance with this approach. You will have to join tables  together but with the proper indexes set up that should not be an issue.

Comment: On the face of it, a surrogate id column may be unnecessary, because of the natural Key on the subsequent 3 columns.

Comment: I understand the appeal to this approach, but I think realistically it causes more trouble than it's worth. Now he has to maintain a Semester table - what additional information is needed in a semester table other than an id? But he must maintain a new semester 1 for every year otherwise students wouldn't be able to retake a course... Again, seems like over engineering IMO

Comment: An semester could have a start date and an end date at least. I'd rather over engineer (which I don't think this does) than not being able to gather needed information at a later point. Requirements tend to change a lot and it's better to be able to be flexible.

Comment: @isick. I think I agree. Semester could be a value such as '20141' or you could split it into year and semester

Comment: so don't use a semesterID then, just call it 'semester'. Even if that were a string, this design is still better than either the multiple tables design or the one-column-per-semester design.

Comment: @MeganSquire I disagree. Putting all three grades into a single table improves performance (no grouping by student_id to get a single year) and reduces space (no need to store redundant semseterIDs or redundant StudentIDs etc). I see no reason to associate a grade as its own entity - it's better to think of it as meta data relating a student to a subject.

Comment: @issick, it also means long queries with manual arithmetic `(semester1+semester2+semester3)/3 AS average`...  Long queries that will all need to be rewritten if the semester space ever changes.  This cost is incurred to gain a performance benefit which is probably not even measurable.

Comment: @BaileyS "...what will be the best solution when performance is a major concern?" Sometimes maintainability is not a sufficient trade off for performance ESPECIALLY when performance is explicitly stated a "major concern".

Comment: how many records are we talking about that this approach would cause unacceptable performance issues? Keep in mind that this relational design is exactly what relational databases are made and optimized for.

Comment: The number of records isn't the issue, it's the per-transaction performance difference I'm arguing. Were I making a system from scratch I would definitely do it this way and performance would not be my highest concern, but per the guidelines of the question I think this implementation has flaws (flaws a multi-column approach do not have). That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @isick Optimization for performance means nothing unless it is being compared to a semantic solution.  Otherwise it is just speculation and a lot of bad code.  Good table design is much more valuable than choosing between solutions that have the same time complexity.

Comment: @BaileyS That's an opinion and not one the author necessarily hods. Both tables are normalized and equally well designed. You're introducing relationships where there need not be any. The solution supports an extensible platform (that's great). Extensibility was never articulated as a concern - the only concern listed was performance and this solution under performs the three column solution in every query I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Joining tables is way more costly than a single select because in a join you're selecting and THEN pairing to create a single huge table.

Why not Solution 3:

Create 1 table with 3 columns (one for each semester). That's effectively what your join will be doing each time anyway. Is there any reason to keep them separate?

**EDIT (explanation):**
Unless I'm misunderstanding something...

A single row in this table would relate a student to a subject and could contain three columns (one for each semester grade). Assuming you have a table for students AND another table for subjects. Containing three semester grades in this table would still be normalized.

```
TABLE
----------------------
student_id
subject_id
semester1grade
semester2grade
semester3grade
```

Comment: 1 table. 4 columns. semester, student, subject, grade

Comment: @isick can you please explain your solution 3?

Comment: @Strawberry Having a single table for all semester grades is an option, but then you'd have to include a group by when selecting multiple students. If you know for a fact that there will only ever been 3 semesters then having it as a many to many relationship isn't required.

Comment: Well, that's true - but it makes life harder when you want to perform comparisons across semesters. A properly normalized table would be as I have described.

Comment: The problem is not well enough defined to select this solution or not, the key piece of information we are missing is how many semesters there are.  If it is always three, this solution is great, otherwise....

Comment: @BaileyS "...we need to incorporate 3 semester grades for each subject by each student." The number is given in the question.

Comment: @isick It looks like an arbitrary number, which might be dangerous to hard-code into the queries, to me.